# intl extension on Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to create a e-commerce project using Sylius. Unfortunately, I'm stuck at the very beginning : Once I get the `Sylius-Standard folder`, I cd into it, I tried to run `app/console sylius:install`, but I get this error :

```
[ReflectionException]
 Extension intl does not exist
```

The thing is, I got this extension ! (Or at least I think so, since there's an `intl` folder in

> /[my_project_directory]/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl

Had anyone faced this problem before ?

Comment: the directory is the Intl component, not the PHP extension

Answer (score 5):

Just install `php5-intl` package on your system.

Answer (score 1):

First install php-intl and  uncommnet **extension=intl.so** in php-ini

Then restart local server(systemctl restart httpd  or service restart apache )